# Problem with Auction Contract when creating an auction

Tags: solidity, truffle, tokens, nft

Hello everyone and thank you for your time.

I am currently implementing an auction contract (based on CryptoKitties contract). The architecture consists of three contracts.

An ERC721 that manages the Mint part:

```
contract CutoutNFTFactory is ERC721URIStorage{

    
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;


    constructor() ERC721("Cutout","COF"){
            

    }

    function createToken(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint256) {
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);    
        return newItemId;


    }


}
```

An Auction Base contract, with the functions I will use later (I'll only put the variables and functions that are creating the problem)

```
    contract CutoutAuctionsBase { 
    
        ERC721 public nonFungibleContract;
        
        address payable contractOwner;
    
        uint256 public ownerCut;
    
        struct Auction {
    
            address payable seller;
    
            uint128 startingPrice;
    
            uint128 endingPrice;
    
    
            uint64 startedAt;
        }
    
       
        mapping (uint256 => Auction) tokenIdToAuction;
    
    }

    constructor(){

            
            contractOwner = payable(msg.sender);

    }

    function _owns(address _claimant, uint256 _tokenId) internal view returns (bool) {
    return (nonFungibleContract.ownerOf(_tokenId) == _claimant);
    }

    function _escrow(address _owner, uint256 _tokenId) internal {
    nonFungibleContract.transferFrom(_owner, address(this), _tokenId);
    }

    function _transfer(address _receiver, uint256 _tokenId) internal {
          nonFungibleContract.transferFrom(address(this), _receiver, _tokenId);
    }

    function _addAuction(uint256 _tokenId, Auction memory _auction) internal {

    require(_auction.duration >= 1 minutes);
    tokenIdToAuction[_tokenId] = _auction;
    emit AuctionCreated(
        uint256(_tokenId),
        uint256(_auction.startingPrice),
        uint256(_auction.endingPrice),
        uint256(_auction.duration)
    );
}


        function _cancelAuction(uint256 _tokenId, address _seller) internal {
        _removeAuction(_tokenId);
        _transfer(_seller, _tokenId);
        emit AuctionCancelled(_tokenId);
    }


        function _bid(uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _bidAmount)
        internal
        returns (uint256)
    {


        require(_isOnAuction(auction));


        uint256 price = _currentPrice(auction);
        require(_bidAmount >= price);


        address payable seller = auction.seller;

        _removeAuction(_tokenId);


        if (price > 0) {



            uint256 auctioneerCut = _computeCut(price);
            uint256 sellerProceeds = price - auctioneerCut;


            seller.transfer(sellerProceeds);
        }


        uint256 bidExcess = _bidAmount - price;

        emit AuctionSuccessful(_tokenId, price, msg.sender);

        return price;
    }



    function _isOnAuction(Auction storage _auction) internal view returns (bool) {
        return (_auction.startedAt > 0);
    }


    
    function _currentPrice(Auction storage _auction)
        internal
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        uint256 secondsPassed = 0;


        if (block.timestamp > _auction.startedAt) {
            secondsPassed = block.timestamp - _auction.startedAt;
        }

        return _computeCurrentPrice(
            _auction.startingPrice,
            _auction.endingPrice,
            _auction.duration,
            secondsPassed
        );
    }



    function _computeCurrentPrice(
        uint256 _startingPrice,
        uint256 _endingPrice,
        uint256 _duration,
        uint256 _secondsPassed
    )
        internal
        pure
        returns (uint256)
    {

        if (_secondsPassed >= _duration) {



            return _endingPrice;

        } else {


            int256 totalPriceChange = int256(_endingPrice) - int256(_startingPrice);



            int256 currentPriceChange = totalPriceChange * int256(_secondsPassed) / int256(_duration);


            return uint256(currentPrice);
        }
    }
```

Finally, the function that is giving me problems in the main Auction Contract.

```
contract CutoutAuctions is Pausable, CutoutAuctionsBase {


bytes4 constant InterfaceSignature_ERC721 = bytes4(0x01ffc9a7);

   address payable nftAddress;
    ERC721 public candidateContract;

    constructor(address _nftContractAddress, uint256 _cut){

        require(_cut <= 10000);
        ownerCut = _cut;

        candidateContract = ERC721(_nftContractAddress);
        
        
        require(candidateContract.supportsInterface(InterfaceSignature_ERC721));
        nonFungibleContract = candidateContract;
    }

function createAuction(
        uint256 _tokenId,
        uint256 _startingPrice,
        uint256 _endingPrice,
        uint256 _duration,
        address _seller
    )
        external
        virtual
        whenNotPaused
    {

        require(_startingPrice == uint256(uint128(_startingPrice)));
        require(_endingPrice == uint256(uint128(_endingPrice)));
        require(_duration == uint256(uint64(_duration)));

        require(_owns(msg.sender, _tokenId));

        _escrow(msg.sender, _tokenId);
        Auction memory auction = Auction(
            payable(_seller),
            uint128(_startingPrice),
            uint128(_endingPrice),
            uint64(_duration),
            uint64(block.timestamp)
        );
        _addAuction(_tokenId, auction);
    }

}
```

There is no problem in compilation, but when I use the Truffle test with this code

```
const account = await accounts[0];
await minter.createToken("https://bafkreic6blqnewlqrorovj476nh3avksvvk7eqgkqe6c234eoud76kiila.ipfs.dweb.link/");

await auction.createAuction(1, 100, 1000, 120, account);
```

I got "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert".

Im really stuck here :( anyone have any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure tokenId=1 ? Probably, you should request it after creation.

Comment: Thank you for your time mate, how can I get the token ID programmatically in the test? I use this method with web3 but in the Truffle test does nothing.

`code`
let tokenId = await transaction['events'].Transfer.returnValues[2];
`code`

Comment: Try to see all the events in collection transaction['events']